# Natural deduction proof from falsehood

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

How does a proof of $⊥\rightarrow A$ (let $A$ be an arbitrary formula) look in the classical calculus of natural deduction?

Comment: Am I the only one that doesn't understand the meaning of ⊥ in this context?

Comment: it is a rule in an intuitionistic calculus of natural deduction but in a classical calculus of natural deduction ex Falso Quodlibet can be proven: Here is my proof: Assume ⊥. Then A. Because: Assume not A. Then ⊥ (that is our assumption). So not not A. douple negation elimination deliveres A. QED

Comment: @toliveria,  $\bot$ means 'false', and $\top$ means 'true'.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a contradiction as a premise (or a correctly deduced conclusion from contradictory premises), then you are allowed to deduce *anything* you want through ⊥ elimination. Assuming a contradiction is no different than assuming what you want to conclude though, so I'm not sure what the point of assuming the contradiction is.

"Modern" logic:

If you want to show ⊥ → A, then simply start a subproof, then assume ⊥, use ⊥ Elim to get A, then end the subproof, and then use → Intro. As seen:

```
1|
 |----
2|| ⊥
 ||----
3|| A                           ⊥ Elim (2)
4| ⊥ → A                        → Intro (2-3)
```

Notice you don't need any premises for this proof.

---

*Without* using ⊥ Elim:

```
1|
 |----
2|| ⊥
 ||----
3||| ~A
 |||----
4||| ⊥                          Riet (2)
5|| ~~A                         ~ Intro (3-4)
6|| A                           ~ Elim (5)
7| ⊥ → A                        → Intro (2-6)
```

This also requires no premises.

You might be better off asking logic questions on the Philosophy StackExchange page:
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In a CLASSICAL calculus of natural deduction, we have no ⊥-Elimination (because we can prove the ⊥-Elimination with the other rules -> douple negation elimination)!!!

Comment: Actually, that is no philosophy.

Comment: Logic is usually included in philosophy and in the philosophy departments of universities. A huge portion of the questions on that page is logic.

Comment: I didn't realize that _classical_ logic is missing that bit, and this "classical logic" certainly belongs on the Philosophy stack exchange. You are right though, one may introduce a negation to get the same result.

Comment: Logic is not a field of philosophy!

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks the following question:

> How does a proof of ⊥→A (let A be an arbitrary formula) look in the classical calculus of natural deduction?

Here is how the proof looks in the Fitch-style natural deduction proof checker associated with the logic text *forallx*:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/